# Command prompt on windows 10 unable to recognise particular files( Documents, images, etc)

Tags: command, prompt

I encountered this while learning the basics of command prompt

```
C:\Users\ratna\Documents>assingnment.docx
C:\Users\ratna\Documents>pics.docx
C:\Users\ratna\Documents>Smith.docx
C:\Users\ratna\Documents>THE MOVIE MANIAC.docx
'THE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
C:\Users\ratna\Documents>Banking Management System.cpp
'Banking' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "
```

Some documents open while others don't, similarly, some pictures open while the rest don't. Please help me,I want to know what's the issue ( Why certain documents are not being recognised??) and how to solve it so that in case if I ever encounter this in the future I can solve it and proceed as well as help others who face similar issues.I am an absolute beginner with no prior knowledge in this field.

Comment: Command prompts don't accept spaces in a file name.  You need to quote the filename, e.g. `"THE MOVIE MANIAC.docx`.  Note the leading `"` double-quote

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Also, I want to clarify another, perhaps a complicated doubt. Before posting my doubt on the forum, I searched on google and I ended up watching some videos which said go to Control Panel>System and Security>System>Advanced settings and then go to "environment variables" to edit the path, etc. I couldn't understand that. Could you please explain when that method will be used, in detail ( Under which circumstances I would have to do that, and also the entire procedure to edit the path under environment variables.) I am a newbie, please help.

Comment: DON'T go into "Control panel ... Advanced Settings" and do *ANYTHING* ... unless you know what you're doing!  Messing up your %PATH% is a great way to trash your system :)  If %PATH% needs to be modified, usually "setup" programs do it on your behalf, when you install new software.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) is more information about %PATH%.

Comment: Tons of gratitude . Thank you so much!!!!